# Advanced Policy Firewall: allow_hosts.rules doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, private-network

I'm trying to open ports for Nimsoft.

In **allow_hosts.rules** I opened ports for private network:

```
tcp:in:d=48000_48020:s=10.0.0.0/8
tcp:out:d=48000_48020:d=10.0.0.0/8
```

During starting apf I see that this ports opened:

```
apf(1781): {trust} allow inbound tcp 10.0.0.0/8 to port 48000:48020
apf(1781): {trust} allow outbound tcp 10.0.0.0/8 to port 48000:48020
```

But anyway, nmap told me that it's closed:

```
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
48002/tcp closed unknown
```

But,

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
48001/tcp open  unknown
```

and

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
48000/tcp open  unknown
```

are opened. In **deny_hosts.rules** no records. So, what also should I do for open this ports in private network?

It doesn't work even if I add this network to trustfull:

```
apf(3453): {trust} allow all to/from 10.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 1):

At first check, what rules are really loaded in your firewall:

```
iptables -L -n -v
```

It may happen that:

- rules are not loaded at all, no matter what you write into mentioned file
- rules are loaded from different file
- your firewall uses eg. custom chains and your rules are loaded into such chain instead in INPUT
- you can't connect because of any other problem, not related to firewall rules, or firewall itself

Comment: iptables -L -n -v shows me empty list. So, no rules loaded?

Comment: Exactly. Now read INPUT/OUTPUT chain policies from the same command. If they're set to DROP, nothing can pass. If ACCEPT, then everything can pass and your connection problem is outside the firewall.

Comment: policy ACCEPT  for INPUT/OUTPUT

Comment: So now it's clear that firewall is not an issue here.

Comment: Hm, any suggestions how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What services are you currently running on this server? Try to connect to them using netcat. Then try to test their ports using nmap (maybe you will spot the real problem this way). Try to install your desired new service and try to connect to it. Check syslog log messages. Check routing of client machine. That's just for start, but probably it will be enough to find the problem.

Comment: I'm connecting to this server using ssh. And running in terminal nmap -P0 127.0.0.1 -p 48002